# Boost different toolsets

Tags: c++, linux, boost

I tried to use different toolsets with boost, but I had no luck.

It doesn't matter what I tell b2 to use, it seems it doesn't bother with me.

Using

```
b2 toolset=gcc stage
```

and user-config.jam

```
using gcc : x86 : g++ ;
using gcc : arm : arm-unknown-linux-gcc ;
```

If arm-unknown-linux-gcc is not available it will fail when running b2 - it doesn't matter that I supply the toolset=gcc-x86.

Is this the right behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: My take on the documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/bbv2/extender.html#bbv2.extending.toolset_modules) is that if any toolset `using` specifies a version, then _all_ `using`s for that toolset must specify a version. Try replacing `using gcc ;` with e.g. `using gcc : 4.7 ;`.

Comment: It was actually at this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *any* usages configures a toolset that is not available in the PATH, compiling boost will fail.
You have to make all configurations valid, or comment them out.